# how to fix mutable variable is accessible from closure warning with a while loop

Tags: javascript

Here's my function that is supposed to validate a name so that there is no duplicates:

```
function validateBucketName(){
        var counter = 1;
        var validated = false;
        var suggestedName = "Bucket " + (vm.buckets.length + counter);
        if(vm.buckets.length === 0) return suggestedName;

        while(!validated){
            var foundIndex = vm.buckets.findIndex(function (bucket) {
                return bucket.name === suggestedName;
            });
            if(foundIndex === -1){
                validated = true;
            } else {
                counter++;
                suggestedName = "Bucket " + (vm.buckets.length + counter);
            }
        }
        return suggestedName;
    }
```

I am getting the pretty common error, that I am aware of how to deal with in `for` loops, but can't figure out how to do that with the `while` loop. Can someone have a look at this?

Ps. This is probably very inefficient way of trying to make sure no duplicate names exist. If you have a suggestion for how to make that better feel free to comment.

Comment: Use `Set` to get O(n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## This is a better approach

- You don't need the `validate` variable, just use `while(true)` because you're going to get the missing `suggestedName`.
- When this condition `if (foundIndex === -1)` is true return the `suggestedName`.

**Look this code snippet with those modifications:**

```
function validateBucketName() {
  var counter = 1;
  var suggestedName = "Bucket " + (vm.buckets.length + counter);

  if (vm.buckets.length === 0) return suggestedName;

  var compare = function(bucket) {
      return bucket.name === suggestedName;
  };

  while (true) {
    if (vm.buckets.findIndex(compare) === -1) {
      return suggestedName;
    else 
      suggestedName = "Bucket " + (vm.buckets.length + (counter++));
  }

  return suggestedName;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the optimization suggestion. My main question was with the 'mutable variable is accessible from closure' warning though. Any thoughts on that? Ps. That code doesn't actually work. There are syntax issues there.

Comment: @konrad you can extract that `compare` function outside from the `for-loop`.  Look the answer.